# Testing Python classes

Tags: python

```
class BMI():
    def __init__(self,name=str,age=int,weight=float,height=float):
        self.__name=name
        self.__age=age
        self.__weight=weight
        self.__height=height
    def get__BMI(self):
        return self.__BMI
    def get__Status(self):
        return self.__Status
    def get__Name(self):
        return self.__Name
    def get__Age(self):
        return self.__Age
    def get__Weight(self):
        return self.__Weight
    def get__Height(self):
        return self.__Height
```

I was wondering if anyone could help with this, the problem is when I try to test it displays an error of "takes 0 positional arguments but 4 were given ":

```
from BMI import BMI

def main():
    bmil=BMI("Odeh",18,140,72)
    print(bmil.get__Name(),"is",bmil.get__BMI(),bmil.get__Status())

main()
```

this is the code from which I am getting the calculations:

```
def BMI(name,age,height,weight):
    Weight=float(input("Enter your weight in pounds: "))
    Height=float(input("Enter your heigh in inches: "))
    bmi=(703*Weight)/(Height*Height)

    if bmi <= 18.5:
        print('Your BMI is', bmi,'which is underweight.')

    elif bmi > 18.5 and bmi < 25:
        print('Your BMI is', bmi,' which is normal.')

    elif bmi > 25 and bmi < 30:
        print('your BMI is', bmi,'overweight.')

    elif bmi > 30:
        print('Your BMI is', bmi,'which is close to obese.')
```

Comment: What problem are you getting ?

Comment: Both the getters and the positional arguments

Comment: The entire code could be wrong.

Comment: In python, you don't ever do these getters. Use a simple member variable. If you need special functions for setting or getting variables, use the `@property` decorator. Also you are setting the defaults to type functions. This is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

well, you have declared both:

```
class BMI():
```

and a function BMI:

```
def BMI(name,age,height,weight):
```

and it is very difficult to tell from the way you have posted the question which is being called.  Based on the error message, I would guess the class definition is getting called when you want to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You defined both a class `BMI` and a function `BMI`. 
Because you definend the function after the Class, `BMI` referes now to the function.

Also you class definition is very odd for python code. 
I guess with the `name=str` you want to define a type for this variable. This is not what it does. It is setting the default for `name` to the function `str`.

Also you would not use these getters. Use plain member variables:

```
class BMI():
    def __init__(self, name, age, height, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
```

The actual bmi is a prime example for a property:

```
class BMI():
    def __init__(self, name, age, height, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight

     @property
     def bmi(self):
         return self.weight / self.height**2
```

Then `BMI.bmi` is always the currrent value for given weight and height.
This makes me think, that this class would probably better be called `Person` or `Patient`.

You should rename the function to avaoid the collision. Functions in python should be named as actions and in lowercase / underscore scheme:

```
def calc_bmi(weight_pounds, height_inches):
    return 0.454 * weight_pounds / (height_inches / 2.54)**2
```